# A certain Pell Equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, elementary-proofs

Recently I came up with a positive solution $((x,y)\neq (\pm 1;0))$ to this diophantine equation
$$
x^2-\left(w^2(2^{n-2}p)^2+2^n(2^{n-2}p)\right)y^2=1,\qquad n\geq 2,
$$
where all variables are  in $ \mathbb{Z}^*$

Is it a known case in terms of the theory? As one can read, for instance, in the notes

- Michel Waldschmidt, *Pell’s equation*, [author pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Emichel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/BamakoPell2010.pdf).

In fact the solutions  are rather elementary ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you fix the equation? There's an unpaired bracket, and also $2^n(2^{n-2}p)) = 2^{2n-2}p$, but it may be that's not what you meant. That means you could also write the last term on the left side as $p(2^{n-1}y)^2$. And what is $w$? A parameter? I can't comment on the solution itself.

Comment: You see that's a Pell like equation where say $$x^2-(w^2p^2+2^n(p))y^2=1$$, all variables as i said are nonzeoro relative integers, and for example for $n=2$ we get $x^2-(w^2p^2+4p)y^2=1$. There are similar equations known in the literature i attached an example file.

Comment: The link to the pdf is broken for me, 404 error. Could you check it?

Comment: ok fixed thank you.

Comment: I don't know what relative integers are, but I guess you mean relatively *prime* integers? I've changed it and tweaked things.

Comment: thanks relative integer is from entier relatif i'll edit

Comment: @ToniMhax cool, learn something every day!

Comment: Well i did  a note on this idea (elementary calculations) that seems not known anyway.